# Angular 4.0.0 custom pipe always sending undefined

Tags: angular, pipe

I am trying to create a custom filter that will filter an array of objects by the object's title attribute, and only display those objects whose title contains the search substring. The problem is, `undefined` is all that gets passed into my pipe component.

The pipe will be used in the template in an *ngFor loop. The template code looks like this:

```
<div class="col-md-2" *ngFor="let strategy of (strategies | NameFilter: searchStrategyText)">
```

In this context, `strategies` is an array of Strategy objects, `searchStrategyText` is a string with two-way data binding to an input field.

The custom pipe code is as follows:

```
import {Injectable, Pipe, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';
import {Strategy} from './strategy';

@Pipe({
  name: 'NameFilter'
})
@Injectable()
export class NameFilter implements PipeTransform {
  transform(strategies: Strategy[], searchString: string): Strategy[] {
    return strategies.filter(strategy => strategy.title.indexOf(searchString) !== -1);
  }
}
```

The versions of angular I am using are as follows:

```
angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.28.3
node: 6.9.2
os: darwin x64
@angular/common: 4.0.0
@angular/compiler: 4.0.0
@angular/core: 4.0.0
@angular/forms: 4.0.0
@angular/http: 4.0.0
@angular/platform-browser: 4.0.0
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 4.0.0
@angular/router: 4.0.0
```

I have scoured the internet and tried a variety of approaches, but this approach seemed closest to what angular describes here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html

What am I missing here? If I left out any important info, let me know.

EDIT:
HTML for input section with two-way data binding for searchStrategyText:

```
<div class="form-group has-feedback has-feedback-left">
                <input class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="searchStrategyText" name="searchStrategyText" (focus)="selectAllContent($event)" type="text" placeholder="Strategy Search">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search form-control-feedback"></i>
            </div>
```

I make the custom pipe globally available via the AppModule by importing it and adding it to the declarations array.

EDIT #2:
I am getting the `strategies` array from a `StrategyService` where I have mocked a `getStrategies()` function that simply returns a mock data class.

Code from component that gets strategies from the service:

```
getStrategies(): void {
    this.strategyService.getStrategies().then(strategies => this.strategies = strategies);
  }
```

StrategyService component:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Strategy } from './strategy';
import { STRATEGIES } from './mock-strategies';
import { ACTIVE_STRATEGIES } from './mock-active-strategies';

@Injectable()
export class StrategyService {
  getStrategies(): Promise<Strategy[]> {
    return Promise.resolve(STRATEGIES);
  }

  getActiveStrategies(): Promise<Strategy[]>{
    return Promise.resolve(ACTIVE_STRATEGIES);
  }

}
```

Mock data component:

```
import { Strategy } from './strategy';

export const STRATEGIES: Strategy[] = [
    {title: "Key Reverse Long Entry",
        description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.",
        type: "Strategy Template",
        modifiedTime: 1461155000,
        symbolList:"S&P 100",
        deployStatus:"LOAD",
        action:"BUY",
        isActive: false},
    {title:"Key Reverse Short Entry",
        description:"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.",
        type:"Strategy Template",
        modifiedTime: 1461154940,
        symbolList:"S&P 100",
        deployStatus:"UNLOAD",
        action:"BUY",
        isActive: false}
];
```

There's obviously a lot more mock data, I just shortened it for brevity.

EDIT #3:
StrategyList component that is controlling all of this:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

import { TabsetComponent } from 'ng2-bootstrap';

import { Strategy } from './strategy';
import { StrategyService } from './strategy.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'strategy-list',
  templateUrl: './strategy-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./strategy-list.component.css']
})

export class StrategyListComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('staticTabs') staticTabs: TabsetComponent;
  strategies: Strategy[];
  activeStrategies: Strategy[] = [];
  totalItems = 0; // from previous html: (allSignals | filter:searchSignalText).length
  filterSelected = false;
  searchStrategyText: string;

  constructor(private strategyService: StrategyService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getStrategies();
    this.searchStrategyText = "initial";
  }

  selectTab(tab_id: number){
    this.staticTabs.tabs[tab_id].active = true;
  }

  getStrategies(): void {
    this.strategyService.getStrategies().then(strategies => this.strategies = strategies);
  }

  getActiveStrategies(): void {
    this.strategyService.getActiveStrategies().then(activeStrategies => this.activeStrategies = activeStrategies);
  }

  exists(strategy: Strategy): boolean {
    let idx = this.activeStrategies.indexOf(strategy);
    if ( idx > -1){
      console.log('strategy is active');
      return true;
    } else {
      console.log('strategy is inactive');
      return false;
    }
  }

  toggle(strategy: Strategy): void {
    let idx = this.activeStrategies.indexOf(strategy);
    if (idx > -1){
      console.log("strategy exists in activeStrategies");
      this.activeStrategies.splice(idx, 1);
      // this.strategyService.cancelStrategy(strategy);
    }
    else {
      console.log("strategy does not exist in activeStrategies");
      this.activeStrategies.push(strategy);
      // this.strategyService.activateStrategy(strategy);
    }

  }

  toggleFilter(): void{
    this.filterSelected = !this.filterSelected;
  }

}
```

EDIT #4:
Error output:

```
strategy-list.component.html:9 ERROR CONTEXT DebugContext_ {view: Object, nodeIndex: 3, nodeDef: Object, elDef: Object, elView: Object}
View_StrategyListComponent_2 @ strategy-list.component.html:9
DebugContext_.logError @ services.ts:571
ErrorHandler.handleError @ error_handler.ts:69
(anonymous) @ application_ref.ts:286
ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:365
onInvoke @ ng_zone.ts:261
ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:364
Zone.run @ zone.js:125
(anonymous) @ zone.js:760
ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:398
onInvokeTask @ ng_zone.ts:253
ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:397
Zone.runTask @ zone.js:165
drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:593
ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:464
zone.js:569 Unhandled Promise rejection: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined
    at NameFilter.transform (name-filter.pipe.ts:11)
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (strategy-list.component.html:9)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (services.ts:273)
    at checkAndUpdateView (view.ts:345)
    at callViewAction (view.ts:700)
    at execEmbeddedViewsAction (view.ts:670)
    at checkAndUpdateView (view.ts:389)
    at callViewAction (view.ts:700)
    at execComponentViewsAction (view.ts:644)
    at checkAndUpdateView (view.ts:392)
    at callViewAction (view.ts:700)
    at execComponentViewsAction (view.ts:644)
    at checkAndUpdateView (view.ts:392)
    at callWithDebugContext (services.ts:645)
    at Object.debugCheckAndUpdateView [as checkAndUpdateView] (services.ts:215) TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined
    at NameFilter.transform (http://localhost:3000/app/name-filter.pipe.js:13:26)
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (ng:///AppModule/StrategyListComponent.ngfactory.js:89:66)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:12620:21)
    at checkAndUpdateView (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:12032:14)
    at callViewAction (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:12347:17)
    at execEmbeddedViewsAction (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:12319:17)
    at checkAndUpdateView (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:12033:5)
    at callViewAction (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:12347:17)
    at execComponentViewsAction (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:12293:13)
    at checkAndUpdateView (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:12038:5)
    at callViewAction (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:12347:17)
    at execComponentViewsAction (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:12293:13)
    at checkAndUpdateView (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:12038:5)
    at callWithDebugContext (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:13020:42)
    at Object.debugCheckAndUpdateView [as checkAndUpdateView] (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:12560:12)
consoleError @ zone.js:569
handleUnhandledRejection @ zone.js:574
_loop_1 @ zone.js:609
drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:613
ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:464
zone.js:571 Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined
    at NameFilter.transform (name-filter.pipe.ts:11)
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (strategy-list.component.html:9)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (services.ts:273)
    at checkAndUpdateView (view.ts:345)
    at callViewAction (view.ts:700)
    at execEmbeddedViewsAction (view.ts:670)
    at checkAndUpdateView (view.ts:389)
    at callViewAction (view.ts:700)
    at execComponentViewsAction (view.ts:644)
    at checkAndUpdateView (view.ts:392)
    at callViewAction (view.ts:700)
    at execComponentViewsAction (view.ts:644)
    at checkAndUpdateView (view.ts:392)
    at callWithDebugContext (services.ts:645)
    at Object.debugCheckAndUpdateView [as checkAndUpdateView] (services.ts:215)
    at NameFilter.transform (name-filter.pipe.ts:11)
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (strategy-list.component.html:9)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (services.ts:273)
    at checkAndUpdateView (view.ts:345)
    at callViewAction (view.ts:700)
    at execEmbeddedViewsAction (view.ts:670)
    at checkAndUpdateView (view.ts:389)
    at callViewAction (view.ts:700)
    at execComponentViewsAction (view.ts:644)
    at checkAndUpdateView (view.ts:392)
    at callViewAction (view.ts:700)
    at execComponentViewsAction (view.ts:644)
    at checkAndUpdateView (view.ts:392)
    at callWithDebugContext (services.ts:645)
    at Object.debugCheckAndUpdateView [as checkAndUpdateView] (services.ts:215)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:712) [<root>]
    at :3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:638:17 [<root>]
    at :3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:654:33 [<root>]
    at Zone.run (zone.js:125) [<root> => <root>]
    at :3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:760:57 [<root>]
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:165) [<root> => <root>]
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:593) [<root>]
    at XMLHttpRequest.ZoneTask.invoke (zone.js:464) [<root>]
```

Comment: I’m not sure if there should be a space between `NameFilter:` and `searchStrategyText`.

Comment: thanks gsc, but it still keeps sending undefined....

Comment: Can you share the component and your two way binding input?

Comment: Sorry, there are spaces in docs as well. So they must be allowed.

Comment: @echonax, i have added the two way binding input html. there isn't any relevant code in my component (besides declaring the variable used in the two way binding), as I didn't think there needed to be because i make the custom pipe globally available via the app-module.ts.

Comment: Also, it's not just the search text that is getting undefined. The strategies array that i'm assuming should be being passed to the filter via the pipe, is also undefined.

Comment: Same code worked fine for me..there is no issue with your pipe code...From where strategies array is coming

Comment: if it is coming form services.first define it as a static value..and check if it is still undefined

Comment: check here https://ibb.co/jVRVOv

Comment: @Karan Garg: I will check out what you sent, but in the meantime i posted some more code related to how i get the array of strategies.

Comment: @MrShantastic can you once try making the pipe impure?

Comment: @KaranGarg switched to impure pipe and it still passes undefined on initial load, but then never hits my breakpoint in the pipe component again, which according to the documentation, i think it should be... does this trigger a possible suggestion?

Comment: used your exact code (without using impure) filter gets executed twice once with the undefined and then with the promise value..everything is working fine for me..with the same code..

Comment: @MrShantastic  you are calling getstratergies method in your oninit lifecycle right?

Comment: @KaranGarg yes.

Comment: I added all of the code form the component class controlling this piece of the html.

Comment: omg..the issue is you need to just add a check if if stratergies exist or not then only clled the method inside the filter.because first time the filter is called strategies is undefined.or initialize strategies as an empty error in your component

Comment: @MrShantastic
transform(strategies: Strategy[], searchString: string): Strategy[] {
if(strategies){
    return strategies.filter(strategy => strategy.title.indexOf(searchString) !== -1);}
  }

Comment: @KaranGarg OMG.... I SWEAR I had a check in there when i was doing my debugging and it still didn't work.... works now though.... Thank you so much for all of the help and suggestions!! Update you answer to include the if check and maybe point out in your answer that that is what fixed it and will accept it as the correct answer... again, thanks a million!

"I always mess up some mundane detail."
"This is NOT a mundane detail, Michael!!"
- Office Space (1999)

Comment: Glad it worked for you.I have also edited my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to just add a check if if strategies exist or not then only clled the method inside the filter because first time the filter is called strategies is undefined or initialize strategies as an empty error in your component

```
transform(strategies: Strategy[], searchString: string): Strategy[] { if(strategies){ return strategies.filter(strategy => strategy.title.indexOf(searchString) !== -1);} }
```

Rest of the code

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'app works!';
  strategies = [];

  constructor(private strategyService: StrategyService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getStrategies();
  }

  getStrategies(): void {
    this.strategyService.getStrategies().then((strategies) => this.strategies = strategies);
  }
}
```

In service

```
@Injectable()
export class StrategyService {
    getStrategies() {
        return Promise.resolve(STRATEGIES);
    }

}

export const STRATEGIES = [
    {
        title: "Key Reverse Long Entry",
        description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.",
        type: "Strategy Template",
        modifiedTime: 1461155000,
        symbolList: "S&P 100",
        deployStatus: "LOAD",
        action: "BUY",
        isActive: false
    },
    {
        title: "Key Reverse Short Entry",
        description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.",
        type: "Strategy Template",
        modifiedTime: 1461154940,
        symbolList: "S&P 100",
        deployStatus: "UNLOAD",
        action: "BUY",
        isActive: false
    }
];
```

and filter

```
    @Pipe({
        name: 'NameFilter'
    })
    export class NameFilter implements PipeTransform {
        transform(strategies: String[], searchString: string): String[] {
if(strategies) //Make sure to run this check otherwise strategies would be undefined for the first time{
return strategies;}

        }
    }
```

First filter gets called with the empty array and then with the final results

Answer (score 0):

```
import {Injectable, Pipe, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';
import {Strategy} from './strategy';

@Pipe({
  name: 'NameFilter'
})
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
@Injectable()
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
export class NameFilter implements PipeTransform {
  transform(strategies: Strategy[], searchString: string): Strategy[] {
    return strategies.filter(strategy => strategy.title.indexOf(searchString) !== -1);
  }
}
```

You are using Injectable() which is wrong.
You should have only one decorator for every class file. Remove this

Comment: did u add it to declarations array of module

Comment: Yes, as stated in the body of the question: "I make the custom pipe globally available via the AppModule by importing it and adding it to the declarations array."